# What word would you use to describe someone who believes humanity needs to come together to survive?

Tags: single-word-requests

Its a hard to describe situation, but if you can imagine a man like Carl Sagan - someone who was a massive advocate of space exploration and science in general.

He once described The Cold War -

> “The nuclear arms race is like two sworn enemies standing waist deep
>   in gasoline, one with three matches, the other with five.”

Someone who sees beyond the wars fought for oil and holds humanities survival above everything; this person knows that the only way to achieve this survival is if we all come together to overcome our problems through science.

I am describing a 'world-view', an ideology if you like.

Perhaps this quote can better explain the situation :

> When you're finally up at the moon looking back on earth, all those
>   differences and nationalistic traits are pretty well going to blend,
>   and you're going to get a concept that maybe this really is one world
>   and why the hell can't we learn to live together like decent people.
>
> — Frank Borman, Apollo 8, Newsweek magazine, 23 December 1968

Edit: I will include an example to better describe the word I'm looking for.

> He carries out his duties in an extremely **adjective** manner

Comment: Can you provide a sentence that illustrates how the word may be used?

Comment: Possibly *internationalist*?

Comment: @Hank Of course: He carries out his duties in an extremely *adjective* manner.

Comment: Please add it to the post :)

Comment: @ConnorHarris That is very close , although it would be more perfect if the definition alluded towards science a bit more- edit: also it would need to include the need for humanities survival - maybe a long shot, the word probably doesn't exist

Comment: I think Nicholas Roerich was one such man, known for his campaigns to bring international harmony and his sponsoring of the Pan-America Pact. Maybe you can find people who have written about him, and see what adjectives they used?

Comment: I would describe this person as "sane" -- an exceedingly rare characteristic anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fascinating. It's hard to find words that don't reference religion, which isn't the intent of your question. (E.g. "humanist".) I'm not sure pacifist works, either, since it's specifically focused on war and peace, admittedly issues critical to human survival. One possible solution is "**omnist**", which is also related to religion. But the OED's second definition seems to approach your goal: "a person who believes in a single transcendent purpose or cause uniting all things or people". Not exactly what you're asking, but it's perhaps close.

Comment: **Humanism** isn't a religion and, altruistically, exists independently of the existence of any other thinking. **Altruism** is a possibility but as a word itself might seem slightly ironic. **Ahimsa** might work but it a) Isn't an English word and b) carries some religious baggage.

Comment: It is quite the conundrum, but the OED definition of omnist is about as close as we can get it seems.

However, ominism still defines a belief in all religions.

I agree that it is fascinating how difficult it is to find a non-religious , English word for this "world-view".

Thanks for your help anyway. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

### Pacifist

Humanity should be regarded as one and disregard all miniscule cultural, religious, (extremist) nationalistic and ethnic differences, only then will peace prevail. This is the main philosophy of a **pacifist**.

A person who believes in peace and strongly opposes war is a **pacifist**.

Comment: Where did your first definition of pacifist come from? While this may be considered a consequence of pacifism, I have never seen this to be a fundamental  attribute of pacifism.

Comment: @CanisLupus I've described it myself. The second sentence is the actual definition of the word. The root cause of conflicts and wars are the ones I've mentioned in the first paragraph, so it would be reasonable (very subtle maybe) to say that conquering those differences is the essence of Pacifism. Isn't that right?

Comment: @Varun, your first definition of pacifism seems subjective and doesn't represent Arnaud's published works on the matter.